# Use Selenium to wait for jQuery popup window to load

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

Ok, I need a Python web driver script to wait for a jQuery pop-up to load. I tried several tutorials but none of them worked for me.

I have:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("xxx").click()
```

//now wait for pop-up
I tried `wait.until`:

```
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
wait = self.wait
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

but it doesn't work. I always get a timeout.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you posted waits for an element with an ID of `myDynamicElement` (for instance, `<div id="myDynamicElement">` will match but `<div class="popup">` will not match).

Comment: yes, i know. But it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: What is the element you're waiting for? How do you know it's there? What do you see when you use "inspect element" from your browser? When you are more specific you are in your question, it's much easier to help you. When you just say "it didn't work", that's not specific enough for us to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) the second argument to the `__init__` method of `WebDriverWait` is a timeout given in seconds.

Currently, you are passing a 20-second timeout for the wait and you are running into timeout problems. If you put a longer timeout, such as perhaps an hour, it should eliminate the timeout problem.

```
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3600)
```

Comment: @nvldk, Do you still get timeout or some other error?

Comment: No error, no timeout. Its waiting. But that element is loaded.

Comment: @nvldk, That implies you're waiting for the wrong thing. If you want more specific help, please post enough code to fully reproduce the problem, including the page you're waiting on and anything else that is necessary to reproduce but nothing more.

Comment: you were right. I was waiting for a wrong thing. Problem solved as soon as I located it to be in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try  a different selector or use a longer exception. Selenium isn't finding the element id = "myID" in the 20 seconds given.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an optimize code but you can try this:

```
def wait_popup ():
    i=0
    while i!=1
        try:
            alert = browser.switch_to_alert()#switch to popup
            alert.accept()
            i=1
        except:
            i=0 
            time.sleep(1)
```